# Values not returning correctly when playing Rock-Paper-Scissors type game

Tags: javascript, python

I am trying to duplicate a script I wrote in Python in Javascript, however, I'm having some issues.  In the both scripts I set a random range between zero(0) and five(5).  Then I find the modular value.  If the value equals one of two numbers, a message is displayed.  If the value equals one of two other numbers, a different message is displayed.  If the value is zero(0) another message is displayed.  The Python script works the way it should.  My issue is with the Javascript version.  I'm getting negative numbers when I shouldn't.  Can anyone explain why the scripts aren't working the same way?

Here is the part where the two scripts should be running the same but aren't.

**PY**

```
def rpsls(player_choice):
    player_number = name_to_number(player_choice)
    print ""
    print "Player chooses", number_to_name(player_number)

    comp_number = random.randrange(0, 5)  
    print "Computer chooses", number_to_name(comp_number)

    difference = (comp_number - player_number) % 5

    if((difference == 3) or  (difference == 4)):
        print "Player wins!"
    elif((difference == 1) or (difference == 2)):
        print "Computer wins!"
    else:
        print "It was a tie!"
```

**JS**

```
function numberToName(computer_throw){
                if(computer_throw === 0){
                    computer_throw = "Rock";
                }

                else if(computer_throw === 1){
                    computer_throw = "Paper";
                }

                else if(computer_throw === 2){
                    computer_throw = "Scissors";
                }

                else if(computer_throw === 3){
                    computer_throw = "Lizard";
                }

                else{
                    computer_throw = "Spock";
                }

                return computer_throw;
            }

            function nameToNumber(user_throw){
                if(user_throw == "Rock"){
                    user_throw = 0;
                }

                else if(user_throw == "Paper"){
                    user_throw = 1;
                }

                else if(user_throw == "Scissors"){
                    user_throw = 2;
                }

                else if(user_throw == "Lizard"){
                    user_throw = 3;
                }

                else if(user_throw == "Spock"){
                    user_throw = 4;
                }

                else{
                    console.log("Please pick a throw.");
                }

                return user_throw;
            }

            function game(thrw){
                var computer_throw = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5));
                thrw = nameToNumber(thrw);
                var difference = Math.abs((computer_throw - thrw) % 5);
                if((difference === 3) || (difference === 4)){
                    console.log("Player wins!");
                }
                else if((difference === 1) || (difference === 2)){
                    console.log("Computer wins!");
                }
                else{
                    console.log("It was a tie!");
                }

                $("#result").append("<p>Player <strong>" +numberToName(thrw) +"</strong></p>");
                $("#result").append("<p>Comp <strong>" +numberToName(computer_throw) +"</strong></p>");

                console.log(difference);
            }

            $("#start").on("click", function(){
                $("#result").children().remove();
                var user_throw = $("#throw").val();
                //game("Rock");
                //game("Paper");
                //game("Scissors");
                //game("Lizard");
                //game("Spock");
```

As you can see, the two functions are identical and should be working the same way, but they're not.  Does anyone have any ideas as to why?  These links are to the working versions.

[Python Script](http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user39_fRkZZ3tVOa_0.py)

[Javascript Script](http://jsfiddle.net/37bkt1mm/4/)

As Joe Frambach pointed out in the comments to his answer, I could have had the winning cases backwards, but as it turns out that wasn't it either.  Here's what's happening.  If I set the player throw to be rock, I get the following cases and values.

**Difference-Player v Computer win respectively**

Player throws Rock: `RvR: 0-T, RvP: 1-C, RvS: 2-P, RvL: 3-P, RvSpk: 4-C`

If I change the user throw to be something else, I get the following results.

Player throws Paper: `PvR: 1-P, PvP: 0-T, PvS: 1-C, PvL: 2-C, PvSpk: 3-P`

Player throws Scissors:  `SvR: 2-C, SvP: 1-P, SvS: 0-T, SvL: 1-P, SvSpk: 2-C`

Player throws Lizard: `LvR: 3-C, LvP: 2-P, LvS: 1-C, LvL: 0-T, LvSpk: 1-P`

Player throws Spock: `SpkvR: 4-P, SpkvP: 3-C, SpkvS: 2-P, SpkvL: 1-C, SpkvSpk: 0-T`

As you can see, the values aren't matching correctly and one of the numbers is actually being replaced.  When the user plays Paper, the same value is set for vs. Rock and vs. Scissors.  Which would cause a conflict in the if statement.  The value of 1 has both players winning, whereas in the logic, the value of 1 should only have the computer winning.  This holds true to all of the other throws.  Can anyone tell me how to fix this

Comment: Post your conversion functions (`name_to_number`, etc.) and how you call the functions above.

Comment: seems like you should occasionally be getting negative numbers in both cases...(e.g. -2 % 5 == -2)

Comment: @sfletche Python modulo works different from JS modulo and that is the answer.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/27e5yrm4/1/ - first 2 methods also simplified

Comment: @EdCottrell see the provided links to see the conversion functions.

Comment: @Shashank Saying Python modulo is different from JS modulo is not the answer as it doesn't explain anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple hack to not get negative numbers:

```
(5 + computer_throw - thrw) % 5;
```

If `computer_throw - thrw` will be at the least `-5`, then adding 5 to it will wrap it back around to 0. In modular arithmetic it is equivalent.

---

**Why not `Math.abs`?**

Consider the [ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)):

```
'Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors', 'Lizard', 'Spock', 'Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors', 'Lizard', 'Spock'
```

and consider the user and RNG pick these:

```
'Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors', 'Lizard', 'Spock', 'Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors', 'Lizard', 'Spock'
                    ^ RNG                         ^user
```

If we `abs` the difference, we'll get `3`.

Now consider the user and RNG pick these:

```
'Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors', 'Lizard', 'Spock', 'Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors', 'Lizard', 'Spock'
                    ^ user                         ^RNG
```

If we `abs` the difference, we'll get `3` again, but that is NOT the correct answer! It should be thought of like this:

```
'Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors', 'Lizard', 'Spock', 'Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors', 'Lizard', 'Spock'
  ^ RNG             ^ user
```

where the correct difference is `2`. Follow the if-else logic, and you see `2` corresponds to the RNG winning.

Comment: Dunno why this isn't getting more upvotes. I can't think of a better way to make JS modulo behave like Python modulo.

Comment: So how do I make it to where if the RNG is scissors and the user is rock, it shows that the user wins instead of the RNG?

Comment: Perhaps the "user wins" and "computer wins" cases are backwards

Comment: I thought that was the case, but it's not.  I've updated my question to show what's now happening.

Comment: Sounds like a new, different question to me.

Comment: Also, did you even read my answer? I said to do `(5+cpu-player)%5`, and wrote in big bold to not use abs.

Comment: Oh, I thought you said to use abs.  Sorry, I got myself all mixed up and forgot to do it your original way.  I figured it would be a different question, so I'll post the new problem as a new one.  Thanks very much for your help.